# Serializing a subset of form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form that embeds another form:

```
<form>
  <input type="text" name="main[name]">
  <textarea name="main[body]"></textarea>
  <div id="embedded">
    <input type="text" name="main[embedded][name]">
    <textarea name="main[embedded][body]"></textarea>
  </div>
</form>
```

I need to serialize the embedded form only.

`$('#embedded').serialize()` results in empty string.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are not embedding another form, you are embedding a `div`.

The [`serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) method can only be called on a `form` elements, or the `form` element itself.

```
var serialized = $('#embedded').find(':input').serialize();
```

> The `.serialize()` method can act on a jQuery object that has selected individual form elements, such as `<input>`, `<textarea>`, and `<select>`. However, it is typically easier to select the `<form>` tag itself for serialization:

Comment: How about `$('#embedded').find(':input').serizalise()` ?

Comment: @Dziamid: That would be better. I forgot that existed. Answer updated.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this, but you could try:

```
$("<form/>").html($('#embedded').clone()).serialize()
```

Comment: I initially tried this, but textareas wouldn't serialize properly.